# sep = '|' not functioning properly in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python 3.6 and pandas version 0.20.3 .

I have a file with text as -

```
17727425 - 1|TM000002|38|cow|country|crow
17727425 - 1|TM000002|64|international|NAME|international ltd
17727425 - 1|TM000002|66|^ference|country|^ference
17727425 - 1|TM000002|80|"|gulf "|DRWENAME|"|gulf "
```

my code for making a dataframe is-

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep="|", error_bad_lines=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Since I'm using `sep = '|'`, it should separate the text by '|' but in the last line of the text, it is separating using `"` 
the output I'm getting is -

`17727425 - 1       TM000002    38  cow             country  crow
0   17727425 - 1    TM000002    64  international   NAME     international ltd
1   17727425 - 1    TM000002    66  ^ference        country  ^ference
2   17727425 - 1    TM000002    80  |gulf           DRWENAME |gulf`

I want to know that for the last line why `sep = '|'` not working correctly and what should be done to eradicate this problem.

Comment: If you'd separate by *all* `|`s, you'd end up with two extra columns on the last line in your example (and something like 'null' for those columns in the other lines). Is that indeed what you want?

Comment: @MaxU - does that bypass the quote issue?

Comment: @pshep123, no, it doesn't. i;ve removed that comment

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the `sep='|'`, but the double quotes.

Pandas by default do no split fields inside strings. So you can change the quote string, e.g. adding `quotechar="'"` (or `\0` or any character that it is not used in the file).

As an alternative you can use add this parameter: `quoting=QUOTE_NONE`, which disregard any quoting character.

Comment: As a side note, it should rather be `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`